# Git merge conflicts in RStudio with line numbers

Tags: r, git, merge, r-markdown, conflict

Image of my git commit

I am brand new to RStudio and Git, learning it for Statistics. 
I am having a problem merging branches in RStudio through Git. From what I understand, Git keeps track of what to merge or delete based on the line numbers. When I made a change to a few lines in my RMD file, instead of committing a change to only a few lines, it deleted everything and rewrote it. Now, this is a problem when I try to merge the branches, because I get merge conflicts, like this  >>>>>>>>>>(HEAD) ==========.

Now, I can clean up the conflicts, commit, and then merge, but I would prefer to prevent the conflicts in the first place. Please explain how I can prevent the conflicts! (No GitHub involved)

Comment: for some reason, my photo didn't show up. Basically in the commit history on rstudio, you can see how the commit is rewriting the entire rmarkdown file, rather than just rewriting the few lines I had changed.

Comment: To prevent merge conflicts, don't make merge conflicts. Basically, don't modify the same file at the same place in two branches and then merge. There is basically no more to say about that. Note that "at the same place" is something like "the same lines or lines close to it". Git uses context around changes, so the exact line you change + some surrounding lines, if you modify those on two separate branches you will get merge conflicts.